# Bootstrap Carousel Showcase show 4 advance 1 problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to use a showcase gallery in my website. Now I'm improving the site with bootstrap and I tried to use this script: http://www.bootply.com/PMDIAzc1Qo

In my website, the showcase don't advance only one box but goes a full round of the sliders.

Here the url: http://goo.gl/UCG3sR